# tutorial and resources for AngularJS Karma

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, jasmine-headless-webkit

I am going to implementing unit testing in my application and for that I have chosen Karma. But I am struggling regarding how to write the test cases using Karma syntax. Please give me some starting resources and tutorial links regarding Karma syntax.

Answer (score 22):

My favorites resources for starting karma was those articles

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html

You should also check the jasmine syntax for writing tests at http://jasmine.github.io/

and how to configure karma
http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html

I hope it helps you

Comment: thanks for your reply but I want to know more about how to test controller and factories in angularjs. Specialy how to test the  backend webservices. Can you please help me on that.

Comment: Check the first article, its really explicit.

For test backend webservices you should use fake data with $httpbackend http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: That yearofmoo.com article is really out of date and the depednencies don't resolve currectly. https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-Testing-Article/issues